# C# How to quicky set a really long string for TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface

One part of a thread will find files that match the condition. The method I use to update the TextBox is `TextBox.AppendText()`. In my case, the amount of files is about `17000`.

I've tried updating the `TextBox` after each file found by using `BeginInvoke`. This caused the UI unresponsive, not anything will appear on the UI until the background thread ends.

I've tried updating the `TextBox` after each file found by using `Invoke`. This is likely success in sending data to the `TextBox`, and I could also see the label which counts the file found increased rapidly from 1 to 17000. This seemed successed because I only saw 5 file paths on the screen. So I decided to use the method `TextBox.ScrollToEnd()` whenever the `TextBox` is updated. However, after the label counts to about 2000, the UI unreponsive again.

I've tried using RichTextBox, its behavior is just like the TextBox.

I've read about the [50ms Rule](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/ui-guidelines-for-async.html). Then I knew the cause is the background thread works too fast, it could generate about 500~1000 pieces of data each 50ms, that's a lot for the UI to handle. This makes sense. I think if the UI only updates every 50ms, then each second it will updates 20 times, and our screen are 30Hz speed. I've known what I was wrong.

Finally, I've tried creating another thread which had only an infinite loop. Inside that loop is the `Thread.Sleep(50)` method, followed by the command to activate the event which calls the UI to update. To do that, I have to use a StringBuilder object to concat many file paths, then send it to the `TextBox` when the event is triggered.

But there is still a problem. As I said before, the thread could find 500~1000 file paths each 50ms, and each path is about 100 characters length. Now the TextBox does not deal with the time, but it have to deal with the length. It will take more than 50ms to append a 50.000 characters length string, so the result is still an unreponsiveness UI.

So my question is: How do I set that 50.000 characters length string to the `TextBox` very quickly?

Right now I can only think about 1 option left. That is I would not show everything to the UI, just a sample each second.

What would you suggest me to do? Which solution is best practice?

Comment: google `wpf virtualization` and `data binding`. Do note that this has a pretty high learning curve if you have to roll your own. So try to stick with the built in ones.

Comment: Thank you so much @Steve. I have just gave it a look, I think it is what I need. And yeah, looks like it's also my last battle.

Comment: What's the point of setting 50k characters into a `TextBox`? Are you expecting a user to read or edit the text?

Comment: @Enigmativity Well, actually there is no point of setting 50k characters into a `TextBox` in my case. I have plenty of ways to serve the users purpose, even if they don't care about the content of the `TextBox`. For example, I have a button which exports the final result of my process to a file for the user to read easily.

Comment: But I think I should always think of the problem in a more sophisticated and professional way, so I can deal with any kind of problem in a real, big application. For example, the recovery lost data apps can sometimes find a lot of lost files and list all of them onto the UI without any lagging, not just some sample data but all of them. Maybe they store data in any kinds of structure view to lessen the UI workload, but the truth is their UI react immediately with user actions. Do you think that's a good thinking in programming?

Comment: @peanut - If you find a real-world scenario with performance issues then we can look at it.

Comment: @peanut - What social network?

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm mainly using Facebook. Actually I don't want to follow your daily life, just the ability to text to you for programming advice. That means I can create any kind of social network account to keep contact with you.

Comment: Thanks, but that's what SO is for - programming advice. Why not ask here?